# Given $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}-x$, determine the value of $f(42.545)$ in 4-digit rounding arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}-x$ is to be computed in 4-digit rounding arithmetic.
(i) Determine the value of $f(42.545)$ in 4-digit rounding arithmetic, and the relative error of this value.

Notation: $fl(a)$ means 4-digit rounding of the value $a$.

$x=42.545 \implies fl(x)=0.4255x10^2$

$fl(x) \times fl(x)=1810.5025=0.18105025 \times 10^4$

$fl[fl(x)\times fl(x)]=0.1811\times 10^4$

$fl[fl(x)\times fl(x)]+1=0.1812\times 10^4$

let $a=\sqrt{fl[fl(x)\times fl(x)]+1}=42.56759331$

$fl(a)=0.4257x10^2$

$fl(a) - x=0.02$

Now the exactly value is 0.01175, so i assume there has to be an instance or instances of catastrophic cancellation somewhere in the computation (did i even do that right?) but i can't seem to find it.

Furthermore, is there another method to calculate this to minimise the error?

Comment: Your computations looks correct. It's not really strange the result is off:  you are subtracting two numbers that are very close to each other and since $x >10$ you can only represent two decimal digits of these two numbers so we would expect an error in the subtraction that is $\sim 0.01$.

Comment: Thanks man! I was wondering why it's so far off unlike the other questions that I have done and now i get it. Thanks so much for explaining!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see that 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+x}\;?
$$

---

This formula shows that the difference $f(x)$ between $x$ and $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is of size $1/(2x)$. The difference in magnitude between these terms explains the cancellation.

It also gives a way to compute the result exactly and without cancellation.

---

Using Taylor series in $1/x$ one can also observe that for large $x$
$$
\sqrt{1+x^2}-x=x(\sqrt{1+x^{-2}}-1)=x(\tfrac12x^{-2}-\tfrac38x^{-4}+\tfrac5{16}x^{-6}\mp…)\\
=\frac1{2x}(1-\frac3{4x^2}\pm…)
$$
where the first two term should already exhaust the given precision.

This confirms the magnitude estimation and gives the next terms for its correction.

Comment: The second computation (and also the first) shows that the difference between $x$ and $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is of size $1/(2x)$. The difference in magnitude between these terms explains the cancellation. The first formula gives a way to compute the result without cancellation.

Comment: Thanks so much for your clear response man!